# Climate Change in the North

Tags: climate-change, climate, temperature

Why has it been so warm in Moscow, Russia the past few winters where the temperatures even overnight have been above freezing when normally it gets brutally cold?

Comment: related: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17199/when-and-where-is-the-atmospheric-greenhouse-effect-strongest/17210#17210 it is my atempt to answer a very simmilar question,others can probably answer it better.

Comment: This is a good question, but can you please edit the title to make it match the question better?  Although warm winters are more likely due to climate change, there are also other effects that cause some winters to be warmer than others.  A good answer will address both aspects.